# Adjusting beforeFind() in AppModel

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have a `status_id` field in everything which manages if things are published etc. I've created this in my AppModel to take care of all the filtering.

```
public function beforeFind($queryData) {
        // Force all finds to only find stuff which is live
        $queryData['conditions'][$this->alias.'.status_id'] = 1;
        return $queryData;
}
```

Which works fine, **until** you go into the admin routing at which point you want to see all the items, and they are being filtered. Is there a way to know if you are in admin routing from the AppModel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer I've got would be to set the route as an attribute in the model from the controller, which you can then check from the Model.

However CakeDC have a Utils plugin bundle which includes a SoftDeletable behaviour which I use now. https://github.com/cakedc/utils

Answer (score 4):

I have experience in a similar situation whereby I use a "soft delete" behavior.

My recommendation is to check whether or not you already have a condition on the `status_id` field and only set it if you don't. Like so:

```
public function beforeFind($queryData) {
    if (! isset($queryData['conditions'][$this->alias.'.status_id'])) {
        // Force all finds to only find stuff which is live
        $queryData['conditions'][$this->alias.'.status_id'] = 1;
    } elseif ($queryData['conditions'][$this->alias.'.status_id'] == 'all') {
        unset($queryData['conditions'][$this->alias.'.status_id']);
    }
    return $queryData;
}
```

This way you have the desired functionality by default and you can also use normal conditions on the `status_id` field when needed.
As a bonus, to ignore the condition, like you want in admin routing, you can use this:

```
    $data = $this->paginate('YourModel', array('YourModel.status_id' => 'all'));
```

It's basically just a convenience to avoid having to pass all the status IDs as a "fake-ish" condition.

That's how I would do it. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can check for admin route in your controller and define it like this:

```
App Controller:

if(isAdmin){
$queryData['conditions']['isAdmin'] = true;
}

In your AppModel:

if(!isset($queryData['conditions']['isAdmin'] & $queryData['conditions']['isAdmin'] !== true )){
$queryData['conditions'][$this->alias.'.status_id'] = 1;
        return $queryData;

} else {
       return $queryData
}
```

This is a dirty way but should work.

Comment: `Notice (8): Indirect modification of overloaded property QuicklinksController::$queryData has no effect [APP\Controller\AppController.php, line 9]` I should mention I'm in Cake2.0

Comment: can you post an relevant example of your quicklinks controller code ?

Comment: That's where your solution is! ;)

Comment: I think this is because the conditions construct in 2.0 is different to 1.3, in the similar way that `$this->data` is now `$this->request->data`

Answer (score 0):

there is no reason for a model to know what the route is. It's purpose is the feed the controller with what's requested. In another word, you must set the condition in the controller, not in the model.

Sorry for having been too brief.

What you're trying to do goes against the MVC design pattern. It's the controller that handles and routes requests made by the client.

```
In your controller:
function index(){
    $data = $this->paginate('YourModel', array('YourModel.status_id' => 1));
    $this->set('data', $data);
}

function admin_index(){
    $data = $this->paginate();
    $this->set('data', $data);
}
```

Even less verbose

You are trying to detect in the model if the request has been made from the admin routing, which is the wrong way to go. The controller handles that automatically. admin_index() handles index request made through the admin route, index() request made through normal route.

It is in the controller that you decide what data you want. You should move the logic you have in your beforeFind method into your controller, like in the example above.

Comment: A more verbose answer would be helpful. As setting model properties in the app controller works to a degree, but it's that reliable.

Comment: sorry about that, see changes in my answer

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the question. `beforeFind()` is run in the model before a find call is executed. That find call is run from the controller. So it's behind the controller.

Comment: I think I understood your question. You are trying to detect in the model if the request has been made from the admin routing, which is the wrong way to go. See my edit

Comment: I don't want to paste the same function into every single controller. I guess I can move it into the AppControllers `beforeFilter()` and then I'll lose the `beforeFind()`

Comment: Yes, if you need it in every controller that's the way to go